# Noether currents for $SU(2)$ symmetric Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem

I'm currently reading Bilenky's Introduction to the Physics of Massive and Mixed Neutrinos.

In chapter 3, section 3.2, we discuss the following Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}_0=\overline{\psi }(x)(i\gamma ^{\alpha }\partial _{\alpha }+m)\psi (x)\tag{Equation 3.2}$$
Where $\psi $ is a doublet of the $SU(2)$ group:
$$\psi (x)=\begin{pmatrix}  \psi ^{(+1)}(x) \\  \psi ^{(-1)}(x) \\  \end{pmatrix}  \tag{Equation 3.1} $$
Where, of course, each of the components is a spin 1/2 field.

It is clear that the Lagranian is invariant under the global phase $SU(2)$ transformation such that
\begin{align}
\psi '(x) &= U\psi \\
\overline{\psi} '(x) &= \overline{\psi }U^{\dagger}
\end{align}
Where
$$U=\exp \left( i\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\tau }\cdot \boldsymbol{\Lambda }\right) \tag{Equation 3.4}$$
We are then presented with the isovector current:
$$j_i^{\alpha }=\overline{\psi }\gamma ^{\alpha }\frac{1}{2}\tau _i\psi \tag{Equation 3.5}$$
(For which, of course, we have $\partial _{\alpha }j_i^{\alpha }=0$).

How does Bilenky conclude equation 3.5 above? I'm familiar (yet not too experienced) with getting currents and I'm having some trouble getting this one.

Comment: this is just a direct result of noethers theorem. It follows the same spirit as with the derivation of em tensor(i mean for the two indicea). You can work it out by first write down the general expression of noether current, keeping a general Lagrangian. Then write ur transformation in infinitesimal version and pkug it in

Answer (score 0):

Working infinitesimally, one has $$\psi’=(1+i\frac{1}{2}\tau\cdot\Lambda)\psi$$
$$\bar\psi’=\bar\psi(1-i\frac{1}{2}\tau\cdot\Lambda)$$
The noether current from a symmetry transformation of field $\psi\mapsto \psi+\alpha\Delta\psi$ is (ch1 or 2. Polchinski)
$$j^\mu=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\Delta\psi-J^\mu$$
Where $J$ is the total derivative change in lagrangian which is $0$ in this case, as you stated already that the Lagrangian remains invariant. Plug things in you find (here you treat $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ as two independent field but contribution from $\bar\psi$ vanishes):$$j^\mu\propto -\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\frac{1}{2}\tau\cdot\Lambda\psi$$
It is unclear if $\tau$ of $\Lambda$ is the generator of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, I will assume $\tau$ is, then you have$$j^\alpha_i=\bar\psi\gamma^\alpha\frac{1}{2}\tau_i\psi$$where $i$ denotes there are $3$ independent conserved current in line with the dimension of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.